# How to add noname stack data to Qt container?

Tags: c++, qt

For example, QList. Now I try to use this way:

```
Struct Data
{
...
}


...

Data * data_ptr = 0;

QList<Data> container;
while(some condition)
{
   if(some condition) 
   {
       data_ptr = new Data(some parameters);
       container.append(*data_ptr);
       delete data_ptr;
   }
...
}
```

I need to use named pointer for creating some data in container, but maybe there is an easier way to create this data, not in RAM, but in stack? Maybe even not needed a name?
I'm sorry, but I can't find this information in the manual of С++ language.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for dynamic allocation:

```
Data data(some parameters);
container.append(data);
```

which can be shortened, by appending a temporary, to:

```
container.append(Data(some parameters));
```

In C++11 or later, you could use brace-initialisation to create a temporary. This will also work if it's a plain aggregate with no constructor:

```
container.append({some parameters});
```

although I've found that some older compilers fail to deduce the necessary type conversions and need a helping hand:

```
container.append(Data{some parameters});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
container.append(Data(some_parameters));
```